# list.longcount query using joins (Linq/Lambda)

Tags: vb.net, linq, join, lambda

I have two lists of class objects (`Shifts` and `Employees`) with which I am trying to create a join. I then need a count of the resulting items that match the search criteria.

Below is the code I am using, but because I can't find a way to pass the result back as a specific 'type' it's defaulting to boolean and warning me that this will cause a problem:

```
' Count Shifts for selected hour where: started before or on this 
"hour" AND ends after or during this "hour" and Department = filter 
value
intShift = Me.Shifts.LongCount(From myshift In Me.Shifts Join 
myEmp In Me.EmployeesList On myshift.EmployeeName Equals myEmp.Name 
Where myshift.Description = "Shift" And myshift.DateStart.Hour <= 
myHour.Hour And myshift.DateEnd.Hour >= myHour.Hour _
And myshift.DateStart.Date = myDay.Date And myEmp.Department = 
strFilter _ Or myshift.Description = "Overtime" And 
myshift.DateStart.Hour <= myHour.Hour And myshift.DateEnd.Hour 
>= myHour.Hour _
And myshift.DateStart.Date = myDay.Date And myEmp.Department = 
strFilter)
```

The search without a join to the employee list and without the matching employee search filters works perfectly but just unable to combine the two.

I have searched for both linq/lambda and inner join examples, but I can't seem to find one that combines these with the `longcount` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to put together a minimal scenario based on your snippet.
If you request `Count` or `LongCount` directly from the query then the result appears to be as expected.

```
    Dim Shifts() = {
        New With {.DateStart = #1/1/2014#,
                  .DateEnd = #1/2/2014#,
                  .Description = "Overtime",
                  .EmployeeName = "Darren"}
    }

    Dim EmployeesList() = {
        New With {.Name = "Darren",
                  .Department = "SO"}
        }

    Dim strFilter = "SO"
    Dim myHour = #1/1/2014#
    Dim myDay = myHour

    Dim query =
        From myshift In Shifts Join myEmp In EmployeesList _
        On myshift.EmployeeName Equals myEmp.Name _
        Where myshift.Description = "Shift" _
        And myshift.DateStart.Hour <= myHour.Hour _
        And myshift.DateEnd.Hour >= myHour.Hour _
        And myshift.DateStart.Date = myDay.Date _
        And myEmp.Department = strFilter _
        Or myshift.Description = "Overtime" _
        And myshift.DateStart.Hour <= myHour.Hour _
        And myshift.DateEnd.Hour >= myHour.Hour _
        And myshift.DateStart.Date = myDay.Date _
        And myEmp.Department = strFilter

    Console.WriteLine(query.Count)
    Console.WriteLine(query.LongCount)
```